# How exactly do a good use and implementation of PDO-SQL Server?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, dll, pdo

I'm trying to do a test server for some post data i'm sending with an app, for that purpose i'm trying to make a very simple php server who work with PDO-SQL Server, the thing is this seems to not be working properly and i can't find good examples out there to know where exactly i'm doing wrong here.

Also, i don't have any problems registered in the logs either, so in that sence i'm blind.

I'm not certain, but i think the problem is the connection not working, however, like i'm blind in it i can't be certain.

Here you have the Code:

ConnectionInfo.php

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "SomeDataBaseUserName";
$pss = "SomePassword";
$db = "YOUR_DATABASE";

$authz = "authc";

// Los comandos auxiliares estan comentados para que no funcionen a menos que sean necesarios

// var_dump($_POST);

try{
    $con = new PDO('sqlsrv:Server='.$host.';Database='.$db,$user,$pss);
    $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
    // $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Success ";

}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage;
}
?>
```

CreateContact.php

```
<?php
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/ConnectionInfo.php');

    $smt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM Contacts");
    $smt->execute(array(':LibName' => $arran));

    while ($smr = $smt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, PDO::FETCH_ORI_NEXT)) 
    {
        echo "Nombre del Libro: "."<nr>".$smr['Contacts_ID']."<br>";
        echo "Nombre de la Region: ".$smr['Contacts_Name']."<br>";
        echo "Nombre del Autor: ".$smr['Contacts_Number']."<br>"."<br>"."<br>";
    }



if (isset($_POST['Name']) && isset($_POST['Number']))
{
    //Get the POST variables
    $mName = $_POST['Name'];
    $mNumber = $_POST['Number'];

    //Set up our connection
    //$connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
    //$connectionInfo->GetConnection();

    /*if (!$connectionInfo->conn)
    {
        //Connection failed
        echo 'No Connection';
    }*/


    else
    {
        //Insert new contact into database
        $query = 'INSERT INTO Contacts (Contacts_Name, Contacts_Number) VALUES (:CNames, :CNumber)';
        //$parameters = array($mName, $mNumber);




     $stmt = $con->prepare($query);
     $stmt->bindParam(':CNames', $mName, PDO::PARAM_STR);
     $stmt->bindParam(':CNumber', $mNumber, PDO::PARAM_STR);

     $rslt = $stmt->execute();


        //Execute query
        //$stmt = sqlsrv_query($connectionInfo->conn, $query, $parameters);

        if (!$rslt)
        {   //The query failed
            echo 'Query Failed';    
        }

        else
        {
            //The query succeeded, now echo back the new contact ID
            //$query = "SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('Contacts') AS NewID";

            $smt = $con->prepare("SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('Contacts') AS NewID");
            //$stmt = sqlsrv_query($connectionInfo->conn, $query);

            $row = $smt->fetch()//sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);

            echo $row['NewID']; 


        }
    }
}

?>
```

Any comment, question, request of clarification or good answer would be much apreciated too

Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You need to return the identity value in the same execution. The way you have this coded you have created a race condition. And you shouldn't use IDENT_CURRENT, you should query SCOPE_IDENTITY in your first execution.

Comment: @bc004346 if i had to guess, the connection.

Comment: Ok @SeanLange consider it done but, it seems to not be connecting at all, can you tell me how to fix that?

Comment: Why do you think it isn't connecting? Why not remove the try catch and let the error happen? You need to step through your code and see what is happening. We can't see what is happening from here and we still don't know what problem you are encountering. All you have said is "his seems to not be working properly". We don't know what that means. Help us help you by providing us information about your situation.